# Add Value To URL On Form Submit With Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this form below when i submit it i want it to append a value to the 6 urls generated from a php query.

```
<form id="emailform" action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" value="" size="30" name="email" id="email">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="continue-button">
</form>
```

This is an example of my link, `sitename.com/demo.php?1=demo&2=haha` How can i use the form and jquery to append `&email=formvalue` to the url so `sitename.com/demo.php?1=demo&2=haha` = `sitename.com/demo.php?1=demo&2=haha&email=formvalue` ?

Please keep in mind that these urls are generated dynamically with a query.

I tried using attr on a but it doesnt work. I know you have to check for the submit then use attr.

```
$('#emailForm').submit(function(){ //listen for submit event

}
```

Comment: use $(form).serialize(); to pass through ajax

Comment: it should happen automatically.. did you try pressing submit button?

Comment: I rewrote the question more clearly

Answer (score 4):

You can use hidden field like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="new_value" value="value"/>
      <input type="text" value="" size="30" name="email" id="email">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="continue-button">
</form>
```

or you can add to action of form like this

```
<form action="http://action_url?new_value=value" method="post">
      <input type="text" value="" size="30" name="email" id="email">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="continue-button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to use markup input type="hidden" to submit the value
Your Form :

```
<form action = "sitename.com/demo.php" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="1" value="demo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="2" value="haha" />
    <input type="text" value="" size="30" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="containue-button" />
</form>
```

Then you just need to submit this form in javascript or jquery.
: )

Answer (score 1):

use serilaize method

```
$('#emailForm').submit(function(){ 

 //listen for submit event
 var all_submit_data = $( '#emailForm' ).serialize() ; 
 //this will have all input fields values in serilized 

}
```

ref : https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: and how do i attached to all the 6 links produced by the query?

Comment: insert all link inside hidden input box ( 6 hidden input I mean)

Comment: The values comes from my database all but 1 which is the email. Now i need when submit is pressed the value gets attached to end of the link. Users will then have the option to click the link if a form is used it redirects.

Comment: I still havent figure this out im not good at all with jquery