# Taking values from two of the fields (Text Inputs) and add them to the URL

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that is posting to a page then forwarding to another page.

What I would like to do is take the values from two of the fields (Text Inputs) and add them to the URL so what I end up with is something like this.

```
index.php?bn=Teddy&on=Bob
```

Below is my basic form.

I looked at using JQuery but as I am not a programmer I was finding it hard to find the right code.

```
<form name="proforms_form_62" class="ccm-ui proform_slider" id="proforms_form_62" method="POST" action="/index.php?cID=239&bID=62&arHandle=Main&ccm_token=1407417080:46dbfa9f839fbf0c4150e18ca8b0f735&btask=passthru&method=entry_form_multipart" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="form_progress">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="multipart" id="multipart" value="1">
    <div class="clearfix proformgroup text">
        <strong>
            <label for="name_of_bear">Name of Bear <span class="required"> *</span></label>
        </strong>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="proform-attributes">
                <div class="required_input" data-handle="name_of_bear">
                    <input id="akID[95][value]" type="text" name="akID[95][value]" value="" class="form_tooltip ccm-input-text" data-original-title="Name of Bear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix proformgroup text">
        <strong>
            <label for="name_of_owner">Name of Owner <span class="required"> *</span></label>
        </strong>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="proform-attributes">
                <div class="required_input" data-handle="name_of_owner">
                    <input id="akID[96][value]" type="text" name="akID[96][value]" value="" class="form_tooltip ccm-input-text" data-original-title="Name of owner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="proforms_submit_group">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-large primary proforms_submit proforms_submit_62" name="proforms_submit_62" value="Create Cert" style="float: right;clear: none;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with the POSTing or the forwarding in regards to the URL parameters? Is it the server or the client that is doing the forwarding?

Comment: well if use $_REQUEST['name_of_owner']; or $_GET['name_of_owner']; in the end page nothing is coming in.

Like this:
    $BearsName = $_REQUEST['name_of_bear']; 
    $OwnersName = $_REQUEST['name_of_owner'];

Comment: I did find this post but couldn't get it working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980892/add-value-to-url-on-form-submit-with-jquery

Comment: I don't know how proforms works but the name of owner and bear would be coming through as something like `$_POST[akID][96][value]` I would think (as the input element is named) and `$_POST` because the form method was "POST" You should `var_dump()` or somehow inspect the `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST` variables to see the structure of the data coming from the form.

Comment: Try this and get:

array(1) { ["entryID"]=> string(2) "14" } array(0) { } array(4) { ["entryID"]=> string(2) "14" ["CONCRETE5"]=> string(40) "d6529bcb16ad7aca67fb6cd1bf76c5e3926522ae" ["ccm-sitemap-selector-tab"]=> string(7) "sitemap" ["_ga"]=> string(26) "GA1.3.758262086.1404831728" }

Comment: I think JQUERY is the way forward

Answer (score 1):

Although you will be receiving this values in $_POST array, you could do what you're asking with something like this:

```
$(".proforms_submit").on("click", function () {

    // Get input values
    bearName = $("#akID\\[95\\]\\[value\\]").val();
    ownerName = $("#akID\\[96\\]\\[value\\]").val();

    // Add input values to "action" attr
    formAction = $("#proforms_form_62").attr("action");
    $("#proforms_form_62").attr("action",formAction+"&bn="+bearName+"&on="+ownerName);

    // Submit the form
    $("#proforms_form_62").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So i did it like this:

```
echo '<a href="bewerber.php?userid='.$userid.'" class="link" "></a>';
```

Use a "?" then the name "userid" and then the value "$userid"
My link would look like this then: bewerber.php?userid=1
And on your next site you then can use that value like this:

```
$userid = $_GET['userid'];
```

So now I can use the userid what is 1 on the next site